# Train Pokemon fast or slow method?

Tags: pokemon-series, pokemon-third-generation

I'm playing Pokemon FireRed, and I want to get a Nidoran from an egg. This little Nidoran will be level 5. (This can be applied to all low level Pokémon)

When you put a Pokémon in first position and then you change it in combat, this Pokémon will get half the earned experience. If its level is much lower, it will get a lot of experience and level up fast (fast method).

Alternatively, I can use the low level Pokémon and fight against Pokémon of a similar level (slow method).

Are there any downsides to the slower method? Will the resulting stats be similar?

Comment: I'm not sure if Firered has it, but a lot of the pokemon games have an item called Exp. Share. If you let the Nidoran hold it he will get some exp. It's a faster and easier method than to switch him every single fight.

Comment: I don't have get, but I think yes there is the ExpShare. Hope I get soon then XD

Comment: I believe rare candies are also no longer detrimental to a pokemon's growth, so once you've done EV training, you can stuff them with sweets.

Comment: @Zibbobz - IIRC Rare candies were only detrimental to growth if you hadn't EV-trained a Pokemon, as EV bonuses are only calculated on level-up. Raising a Pokemon to level 100 with Rare Candies without first EV training it would mean that the EVs it earns never translate into stats.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, it doesn't really matter how a pokemon is levelled up, it will gain the same stats.

EV training will make a difference depending on *which* pokemon you fight, and there are plenty of other posts on here that explain EV training, but otherwise your pokemon will have the same total stats whether they level up by either your fast or slow methods.

Comment: Perfect then,so I will do "Fast Training" to do it in less time. ;) Thanks!

Comment: @shudy Just do the EV training before the Lvl training. Otherwise you have to reset the EV with berries before you start the EV training.

Comment: Good answer. Note that in later generations (I believe Gen 6 is the first time it appears) you can access Super Training which makes the process much faster and more transparent.

Answer (score 4):

Couple of things I would like to clarify, which I guess could be called more of an addition to [Pyritie's answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/218684/58396) since the question was tagged to address Pokémon from not just one generation.

> I'm playing Pokemon FireRed, and I want to get a Nidoran from an egg. This little Nidoran will be level 5.

Note that this happens in FireRed/LeafGreen and games before it. Any games that got released later have Pokémon hatching at level 1.

> When you put a Pokémon in first position and then you change it in combat, this Pokémon will get half the earned experience. If its level is much lower, it will get a lot of experience and level up fast (fast method).

This has also changed in recent games. As from Black/White, if two Pokémon battled the same opponent and win, the Experience gained will not be equally shared between the two Pokémon, but the lower leveled Pokémon will get higher Exp. The reason why you might see something a bit similar in FireRed is that lower level Pokémon require less Exp to level up (for the Nidoran lineup, the change is roughly cubical, i.e. it follows a trend similar to requiring 1, 8, 27, 64, 125 exp each time it levels up).

To your question now, yes, what only matters for your Pokémon to get their final stats (considering only their training) is the type and amount of Pokémon they get Exp from. The level or amount of Exp received does not have any effect.

To illustrate, if your Nidoran battles 40 Rattata on its own, it will get 40 Speed EVs (that basically represents 10 more points in the speed stat). If the same Nidoran had battled 40 higher leveled Rattata but you always switched for another of your Pokémon to take it down, both your Nidoran and your other Pokémon would get the 40 Speed EVs.

Personally, I like to give my Pokémon vitamins once I can get a constant supply of Pokédollars. Each vitamin can up a particular stat by 10 EVs to a maximum of 100, which is already a lot!